# OpenShift API: how to get a list of all pod labels?

Tags: openshift

I am drowning in OpenShift documentation but couldn't locate anything useful for what I am trying to achieve. Maybe someone can provide me a pointer or hint to do the following:

I am trying to get a list of specific labels of all pods, ideally using a GET request to the OpenShift API (i.e. via a browser URL). I have come this far to get me a list of all pods:

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token here>" "https://api.<OpenShiftServer>:6443/api/v1/namespaces/<project>/pods/"`

This yields me a huge (>2MB!) JSON document listing tons of information re. all pods running in our environment which looks like so:

```
{
  "kind": "PodList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "resourceVersion": "..."
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "metadata": 
        ...
        "labels": {
          ...
          "app": "zhs-administration-domain",
          "app.kubernetes.io/version": "1.14.0",
          ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

But for the issue at hand I am actually only interested in two specific labels called `app` and `app.kubernetes.io/version` of each pod.

Is there a way (e.g. via further URL segments or URL query-parameters) to restrict the output to only return the labels of each item?

I.e. I would like to get only the elements whose "XPath" matches `items/metadata/labels`.
Is there a way to filter for just that data?

If I have to extract just the matching labels from the result that would be OK but I want to avoid having to parse *the entire* JSON structure just to extract these two fields from each "item".

Note: the curl-command here is just to "develop" the required URL. It will eventually be used in a Java-program to open a URLConnection and get the raw data. So, simply grep-ing for those lines is not an option here.

Hope I could make myself clear...

Comment: If you can use JSON parser like jq command, you can filter the output from the API.

Comment: Ah - yes - that would probably have been a solution, too. Hadn't thought about it. Meanwhile I wrote me a Groovy-Script. Groovy has this very nice JsonSlurper library that made the reading and filtering really easy. Not a command-line solution but it does the job. Thanks!